# The add method is just printing True. How to print the values of the web element after converting it to the List<String>

Tags: java, selenium

I have converted my web element list to List string. But how to print the values of that particular web element.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a/span[2]")).click();
Thread.sleep(4000);
List<WebElement> others = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[5]/ul/li/a/label/span"));
List<String> othr = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.println("Total number of mail under other provider: "+others.size());
System.out.println("List of others id's");
for (WebElement webElement3 : others) {
    othr.add(webElement3.getText());
}
```

Comment: I don't see how given the current code you've posted that "True" is being printed. Please check the code you have posted and run it again and update the question with the updated results.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the values in two way. Either you can print in the value in the same loop when you are adding the values in the list or you can print the values from the list when all the values are added in it.
For example:

```
for (WebElement webElement3 : others) {
//print the values while adding it in list
    System.out.println(webElement3.getText());
    othr.add(webElement3.getText());
}

//or print it when the list insertion is complete
for(int i=0;i<othr.size();i++){
    System.out.println(othr.get(i));
}
```